# KPI's don't transfer on RS.exe SSRS Server Migration

Tags: sql-server-2016, migration, ssrs-2016

I'm attempting to do a server migration with SSRS 2016 to Power BI (March 2018 release).  I have been successful at getting my Data Sources, Data Sets, Folders, Reports, settings and subscriptions to come across.  Each of the KPI's that we set up have failed to transfer.  Other than this it's essentially the last thing that needs to transfer.
I'm using the process outlined here;
[RS.exe migration process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/sample-reporting-services-rs-exe-script-to-copy-content-between-report-servers?view=sql-server-2017)

Has anyone else run into the issue using RS.exe that none of the KPI's transfer?  Is there a workaround or some step that I have to take to get that to work?
I've been looking on Microsofts pages for a bug report but haven't been able to locate anything.

I realize that I can script copy the records out of the Catalog table but I was hoping for something a bit more out of the box. 
Also, to clarify, we are using Power BI report server through our Enterprise license with SA.  I have verified that I can create a KPI manually on the new server.

Comment: Are they refusing to insert to the new server, or are they copying over then failing to run? Any error messages? Can you run the script for 1specific example?

Comment: They were erroring out on loading into the destination server.  I haven't been able to find any other error messages.  At this point, the migration has already occurred.  I ended up manually copying them over since there were only 50 or so of them.